# What is the best way to develop a dynamics 365 plugin that requires dependent dlls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-365

Using Visual Studio 2017/2019 and Dynamics 365 OnPremises what is the recommended way to develop a plugin that contains other dependency dlls.

An example walkthrough of the process would be ideal.

Comment: Plugins seem to be intended primarily for front end customization not full on business applications.

The reason I went with plugins was we are a small business and a 2 developers!  So keeping it simple and direct.and wrapped up into a single on site plugin seemed a good idea. 

I am currently investigating WCF and so far it seems to be communicating fine with the CRM plugin.  This means i can separate my concerns between front end (in the plugin) and back end (the services).  Still in the proofing stage but hopefully I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Merging External dlls into CRM is not supported and especially**

To bind external dlls into your crm plugin dll, you will need to merge them.

I often use ILmerge to merge external dlls.

Below two articles will give you more idea

[Article 1](http://develop1.net/public/post/2018/10/21/ILMergeNotSupported)

[Article 2](https://nishantrana.me/2017/05/17/using-ilmerge-for-plugin-in-crm/)